# What is the correct way to call a function inside a class extended in another class - PHP

Tags: php

I need to obtain $foo from here:

```
include_once("root/MyActiveRecord.php");

class MyClass extends MyActiveRecord {
    public static function MyFunction($table,$where){
        $foo = Count($table,$where);
        return $foo;
    }
}

$bar = MyFunction($table,$where)
print $bar;
```

Please note that Count already exist into MyActiveRecord, as you can see here at line 582:
https://github.com/walterdavis/myactiverecord/blob/master/MyActiveRecord.php

It's that correct? Or I need to write:

```
$foo=MyActiveRecord::Count($table,$where);
```

Comment: Similarly to what @RiggsFolly said, you need to reference the class appropriately by calling `MyClass::MyFunction($table, $where);`

Comment: Woops Yes thats what I ment to write, :)

Comment: Although you use the `function` keyword to define both, when it's inside a class it's actually a *method*. (BTW, that class is **ancient**, it still supports PHP/4 and PHP/5 was released 14 years ago.)

Comment: You should throw that class away (`MyActiveRecord`). Not only is it using a lot of static function calls (in the format: `MyActiveRecord::someMethod()`) which will make it impossible to extend and rewrite some methods (since the class will use the original methods when calling those methods instead of your implementations). But the worse thing is that it uses the old and deprecated `mysql_*`-functions.

Comment: Well according to the history of it on GitHub it was last updated in 2010, so that class `(MyActiveRecord)` is around 8 years old.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see the `Count` method is not static so you need to instantiate an object first inside `MyFunction` which is static.

```
$obj = new self();
$obj->Count($table, $where);
```

Or just make `MyFunction` non-static and use `$this`:

```
$this->Count($table, $where);
```